# How to produce the following images (gabor patches)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am trying to create four gabor patches, very similar to those below.
I don't need them to be identical to the pictures below, but similar.

Despite a bit of tinkering, I have been unable to reproduce these images...
I believe they were created in MATLAB originally. I don't have access to the original MATLAB code.

I have the following code in python (2.7.10):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import toimage  # One can also use matplotlib*

data = gabor_fn(sigma = ???, theta = 0, Lambda = ???, psi = ???, gamma  = ???)
toimage(data).show()
```

*[graphing a numpy array with matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html)

gabor_fn, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter#Example_implementation), is defined below:

```
def gabor_fn(sigma,theta,Lambda,psi,gamma):
    sigma_x = sigma;
    sigma_y = float(sigma)/gamma;

    # Bounding box
    nstds = 3;
    xmax = max(abs(nstds*sigma_x*numpy.cos(theta)),abs(nstds*sigma_y*numpy.sin(theta)));
    xmax = numpy.ceil(max(1,xmax));
    ymax = max(abs(nstds*sigma_x*numpy.sin(theta)),abs(nstds*sigma_y*numpy.cos(theta)));
    ymax = numpy.ceil(max(1,ymax));
    xmin = -xmax; ymin = -ymax;
    (x,y) = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.arange(xmin,xmax+1),numpy.arange(ymin,ymax+1 ));
    (y,x) = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.arange(ymin,ymax+1),numpy.arange(xmin,xmax+1 ));

    # Rotation
    x_theta=x*numpy.cos(theta)+y*numpy.sin(theta);
    y_theta=-x*numpy.sin(theta)+y*numpy.cos(theta);

    gb= numpy.exp(-.5*(x_theta**2/sigma_x**2+y_theta**2/sigma_y**2))*numpy.cos(2*numpy.pi/Lambda*x_theta+psi);
    return gb
```

As you may be able to tell, the only difference (I believe) between the images is contrast. So, `gabor_fn` would likely needed to be altered to do allow for this (unless I misunderstand one of the params)...I'm just not sure how.

---

[image]

---

UPDATE:

```
from math import pi
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = gabor_fn(sigma=5.,theta=pi/2.,Lambda=12.5,psi=90,gamma=1.)

unit = #From left to right, unit was set to 1, 3, 7 and 9.
bound = 0.0009/unit

fig = plt.imshow(
                  data
                 ,cmap = 'gray'
                 ,interpolation='none'
                 ,vmin = -bound
                 ,vmax =  bound
)
plt.axis('off')
```

Comment: You don't need to alter `gabor_fn` at all, just play with the parameters. `sigma` controls the smoothing or the radius, `theta` the angle, `psi` the phase... Try playing with those 3 until you get more or less the `shape` you want, and then with `lambda` and `gamma` for the *contrast* (which is the strenght).

Comment: @imaluengo Thanks for the reply. Sadly, while I can generate the one in the bottom right with: `gabor_fn(sigma=55,theta=pi/2,Lambda=150,psi=90,gamma=1)` the others still elude me...

Comment: @InNoam Please post the results you get (maybe you could also scale down the images a bit). I believe the problem is not the generation of the image but the presentation. By default Matplotlib scales images to their min/max value. If you change the amplitude of the gabor patch (seems like what you want to achieve), you will not see a difference in the displayed image.

Comment: You can also try playing with other versions of gabor filters: [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html?highlight=gabor%20filter#skimage.filters.gabor_kernel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is a visualization problem (although, I think you are chossing too large parameters).

By default matplotlib, and scipy's (toimage) use bilinear (or trilinear) interpolation, depending on your matplotlib's configuration script. That's why your image looks so smooth. It is because your pixels values are being interpolated, and you are not displaying the raw kernel you have just calculated.

Try using matplotlib with no interpolation:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(data, 'gray', interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

For the following parameters:

```
data = gabor_fn(sigma=5.,theta=pi/2.,Lambda=25.,psi=90,gamma=1.)
```

You get this output:

[image]

If you reduce lamda to `15`, you get something like this:

[image]

Additionally, the sigma you choose changes the strength of the smoothing, adding parameters `vmin=-1` and `vmax=1` to `imshow` (similar to what @kazemakase) suggested, will give you the desired *contrast*.

Check this *guide* for sensible values (and ways to use) gabor kernels:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_gabor.html

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `toimage` scales the input data so that the min/max values are mapped to black/white.

I do not know what amplitudes to reasonably expect from gabor patches, but you should try something like this:

```
toimage(data, cmin=-1, cmax=1).show()
```

This tells `toimage` what range your data is in. You can try to play around with cmin and cmax, but make sure they are symmetric (i.e. `cmin=-x, cmax=x`) so that a value of 0 maps to grey.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.